# How to identify an adverbial clause

Tags: word-usage, adverbs, clauses, relative-clauses, subordinate-clauses

I find it difficult to identify an *adverbial clause* in the following sentence:

> Saturday is the day when I get my hair done.

Is the clause "when I get my hair done" adverbial?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"when I get my hair done" is not an adverbial clause in your example.  It's a relative clause modifying "day".  Similarly, in "My hairdresser's is the place where I get it done", "where I get it done" is a relative clause modifying "place".

It is more obvious that these are relative clauses if you use "on which" in place of "when" in your example, or "at which" instead of "where" in the example I gave.

Comment: Of if you don't want to pied-pipe, you can just say _the place that I get my hair done at_ or _the place I get my hair done_.